# Override controller from Grails Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, overriding, controllers

I was using Grails 2.0.4 and there was a LoginController in a plugin project that I was using instead of SpringSecurity's Login Controller.

Now I am migration to Grails 2.4.2 and it's not working anymore.

It worked when I put my controller inside of the project, but I'd like to put it back in the plugin project.

Any ideas on how to force it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your URL mapping you can be explicit about which login controller you are mapping to:

```
// grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        '/alphaLogin' {
            controller = 'login'
            plugin = 'alpha'
        }

        '/betaLogin' {
            controller = 'login'
            plugin = 'beta'
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you don't have to provide a mapping to both of them.  You can just map to the one you want and provide no route to the other.

Comment: It worked! :) Thanks. I just had two issues: one regarding the plugin name. My plugin in defined as "myplugin" but I had to put it like "myPlugin" in URLMappings.
The second one was that I also had to move from default package to another package inside of the application.